# Html align text to center

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am making some portfolio and this question occurs in my favourite music portfolio. You can see the music name that is long will go to another line and will automatically align the text to center. However, the music name that isn't long will not align text to center. How can I do?

```css
img{
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
}
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.music{
  background: #123;
  width: 400px;
  height: 90px;
}
a{
  display: flex ;
}
p{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <article class="music">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/RgKAFK5djSk/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
            <p>See you again</p>
          </a>
       </article>
        <article class="music">
            <a href="#" class="music-child">
              <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/o3KXwe-7A-I/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
              <p>Deep Chills - Run Free</p>
            </a>
        </article>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `display: flex;` in your p tag, and you may want to add `width: 100%;`

```css
img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.music {
  background: #123;
  width: 400px;
  height: 90px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <article class="music">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/RgKAFK5djSk/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <p>See you again</p>
      </a>
    </article>
    <article class="music">
      <a href="#" class="music-child">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/o3KXwe-7A-I/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Deep Chills - Run Free</p>
      </a>
    </article>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add **margin-left** and **margin-right** in p tag as following:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

So complete style of p tag is as following:

```
p {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Hope to helpful!